# $x^2 \equiv k \pmod p$ - quick way

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We have equation: $x^2 \equiv k \pmod p$

We have $k$ and $p$ ($p$ is prime).

We are looking for $x$.

Is there a quick way to find $x$?

Comment: Not like this. You need to know $k$.

Comment: "We have $k$ and $p$ ($p$ is prime)."

Comment: If you have $k$ and $p$, then you can get the equation $x^2 = p\cdot m+ k$ for some integer $m$.

Comment: "quadratic residue" sound like a good start.

Comment: Look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm
and here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm

In my opinion, the second method is easier.